# ORA-00936: missing expression

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I tried to solve this issue , but it stil there .
Could you help me to solve it?

```
insert into diskgroup_size ( type1 , name , total_mb , used )
  VALUES ( SELECT 'BANK', name, total_mb, (total_mb-free_mb) as "USED"
          from v$asm_diskgroup_stat@T24PRD ) ;
```

**Note** : 
When I use select Statement without insert , I get all data .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `insert ... select` you don't use the `values` clause:

```
insert into diskgroup_size ( type1 , name , total_mb , used )
SELECT 'BANK',name,total_mb,(total_mb-free_mb)
from v$asm_diskgroup_stat@T24PRD ;
```

The [syntax diagram in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/statements_9014.htm#i2121671) shows that you use a values clause or a subquery, not both.

Answer (score 0):

Do `INSERT SELECT` instead of `INSERT VALUES`:

```
insert into diskgroup_size ( type1 , name , total_mb , used )
   SELECT 'BANK', name, total_mb, (total_mb-free_mb) as "USED"
   from v$asm_diskgroup_stat@T24PRD
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the `INSERT`statement correctly, try this query:

```
INSERT INTO diskgroup_size ( type1 , name , total_mb , used )
SELECT 'BANK',name,total_mb,(total_mb-free_mb) as "USED"
FROM v$asm_diskgroup_stat@T24PRD
```

Hope this will help you